How can I change the font weight of an SF Symbol in a List swipe action in SwiftUI?
So it’s really hard to customise SwiftUI List swipe actions. All I want is an SF Symbol checkmark with a bold font weight but iOS insists on rendering it at a regular weight.

Normally you can change an SF Symbol like this:
Image(systemName: "checkmark").fontWeight(.bold)

But unfortunately when it's part of a swipe action, iOS seems to override it somehow and just render the plain symbol with regular weight. (It also applies the fill variant of the given symbol if it exists whether you want it or not!)
List {
  ForEach(events) { event in
    Text(event)
      .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
        Button(action: {}) {
          Image(systemName: "checkmark")
            .fontWeight(.bold)   // <-- this is ignored
        }
      }
  }
}

I've tried all the variations of this I can think of but nothing works.
Image(systemName: "checkmark").fontWeight(.bold)
Image(systemName: "checkmark").font(.title.weight(.bold))
Text("\(Image(systemName: "checkmark").fontWeight(.bold))")
Text("\(Image(systemName: "checkmark"))").fontWeight(.bold)

It's as though SwiftUI is digging around inside the view I give it to pull out the image so it can style it the way it wants.
The only workaround I've found so far is to make an image on the fly that renders the symbol the way I want, or just load my own SVG, but these both make supporting Dynamic Type a pain.
What's the tidiest way to accomplish this?

Pretty sure this is not supported. You'd have to use one of those workarounds you mentioned. Supporting Dynamic Type is as easy as putting a @ScaledMetric modifier.
